# What anime is this black sword from?

Tags: merchandise

Here is a pic:

[image]

I got this sword at the Facts convention in Belgium, and suspect it's from an anime, but I am not sure which one. Is there anyone who knows it?

Comment: Despite the fact that I was able to identify the sword, please note that image-only identification requests are usually frowned upon in this community — [in fact, this one is borderline only because it is about cosplay/merchandise](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2725/49). It would be great if you could add some more details, such as where you got the item from, if it has any marks that help identify what's its manufacturer or collection, etc. — so that we might be able to point you to an actual page on the product, for instance, so that you know the exact product you have in your hands.

Comment: I understand I got the sword from a convention soo I don't know the original retailer, but will take the advise into account.

Comment: Feel free to edit any more relevant information into the question — the more you add, the more likely your post is to be able to help future users (who may have acquired the sword in the same convention, for instance).

Comment: It looks awesome if I do say so myself!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be [Uchiha Sasuke](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sasuke_Uchiha)'s [Sword of Kusanagi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kusanagi_%28Sasuke_Uchiha%29), from the [Naruto series](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_%28series%29):

[image]

However, I'm not sure whether or not [the Uchiha crest](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uchiha_Clan) is ever shown to be on the hilt of the sword in the series.

Answer (score 3):

It's safe to assume that [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7A84JA) is what you've purchased.

[image: Sasuke Uchiha kusanagi Replica Sword]

JNat was correct.